# Sql server generate serial number

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server query. I remember I found a way to generate serial number which don't use ROW_NUMBER function when select data. but I don't remember now

It like this:

```
DECLARE @num int
SET @num = 0
SELECT ??? as [Index], Name FROM Product

The result will be:
Index    | Name
1        | Rug
2        | Water
3        | Oil
```

I remember ??? like @num = @num + 1 and in this it used a function CAST or ISNULL or CONVERT or another (I don't remember, but I'm sure that it don't use ROW_NUMBER() function)

Is there a way to do that?

My problem when I use Row_number():

```
select Id, Case when [type] = 'abc' then 1 else 0 end as Classification,
       ???? as DisplayOrder
from Product
order by Classification, ..., ..., ...
```

??? how to use Row_number() here?
I try to Row_number(over order by (select 1)) but it 'order by Classification,...' statement run after Row_number is generated. It mean serial number is generated before order by statement action.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `row_number()`. That would be the natural way to do this.

Comment: You remember incorrectly.  A SQL Server `SELECT` can assign a value to a variable.  Or, it can return columns.  But, it doesn't do both at the same time.  MySQL does allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I see in My SQL, it is @@num := @@num + 1

Answer (score 1):

try

use `Row_Number()`

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as [Index], Name FROM Product
```

EDIT 2:

Using `Identity column` and `Temporary Table`

```
create table #x([Index] bigint identity(1,1),Name varchar(200))

insert into #x(Name)
SELECT Name FROM Product

select * from #x

drop table #x
```